# What credentials I have to enter when I try to attach to a process?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-web-app-service

When I try to attach to a process (Azure hosted app service) it prompts me with a window to enter credentials. What credentials should I enter there? I exported the publishing profile from my Azure portal as I read but I am on the same machine I published the app in the first place. Why would I need it anyway?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VSUN.png)

Answer (score 1):

> What credentials I have to enter when I try to attach to a process?

According to your screenshot. We can use the name from publishing profile.(the username part is NAME\$NAME). publishing profile can be download from azure portal.

[image]

[image]